I am trying to create training data for a game in python. For that, i chose to create a two dimensional list. But list is not updating properly
This is the part of the code i wrote:
for e in range(episodes):
    qm=random.randint(0,5)
    env.game(action)
    fps.tick(1)
    screen.fill(bgcolor)
    s=env.get_state()
    rew=s[12]
    q1=rew+g*qm
    for k in range(12):
        tlistc[k]=s[k]
    tlistc[12]=action
    tlistc[13]=q1
    tlistm.append('a')
    tlistm[e]=tlistc
    if s[13]==1:
        env.game_reset()        
    action=random.randint(0,3)
    print(tlistm)

This is what being returned to me
But after every iteration, all the items of the tlistm updates to tlistc, instead of only the last item.
Am i making some mistake or is there something i am missing?
I checked and rechecked my code, butcant seem to understand the problem..

Please create a minimal reproducible example.

can you add comments in your code to make it more descriptive?

tlistc is created outside the for loop. Each iteration, you are mutating the same object.
You should instead created a new tlistc inside the for loop.

Thanks, that worked. Apparently i didn't understood the concept of mutation properly. This helped a lot.
